# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9813023219"

Tags: java, string, processing

I'm using serial event to pass rfid tags read from arduino to processing. In the serial event I am parsing and converting the variable to an integer. This working for the most part, only one rfid card keeps throwing an error.

```
void serialEvent(Serial thisPort)
{
  String inString = thisPort.readString();
  if(inString != null)
  {
    Serial connect1 = (Serial) connections.get(0);
      if(thisPort == connect1 )
      {
        Chair chair = (Chair) chairs.get(0);
        if(inString.contains("UID Value:"))
        {
          int p2 = inString.indexOf(":");
          String pString = inString.substring(p2+1); 
          String pString2 = pString.substring (0,10);
          //println(pString2);
          pString2.trim();

          println("String length: " + pString2.length());

          chair.setRFID(pString2);
          println(pString2);
        }

      }
  }
}

void setRFID(String r)
  {  
     try{
       this.rfid = Integer.parseInt(r);
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }

     //set position of person to chair
     for (Person person : people)  
     { 

        //println(this.rfid != chair.rfid);
        //println(this.rfid + "," +  "person: " + person.ID + "," + person.RFID);
        if(this.rfid == person.RFID)
        {
          person.setPos(this.pos);
          this.personID = person.ID;
        }
     }
  }
```

The try-catch is not working, and this line is causing the problem this.rfid = Integer.parseInt(r);. I thought it might be a malformed string but the strings seems ok. Here the results of checking string consistency:
String length: 10
1811524219
String length: 10
1942302231
String length: 10
1010368230
String length: 10
9813023219

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`9813023219` is an invalid `Integer` as it is greater than [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE), which is `2147483647`. Use [`Long`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) instead, who's [`MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE) is `9223372036854775807`.

Answer (score 2):

You have exceeded the maximum value for an integer. I suggest using a `long` instead.

Check for this by displaying `Integer.MAX_VALUE` - no int can exceed this value.

`java.long.NumberFormatException` is thrown when a given string does not match the expected layout.

Answer (score 1):

The number `9813023219` is out of range for `int` data type, try changing your data type to `long` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

9813023219 is Invalid Integer,  You can use Long for your requirement. If RFID is not exceeding Long.MAX_VALUE.